# Safari cambia el color de la barra del celular - página web

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Tengo un sitio que me derivaron para que haga unos arregos, y me doy con que cuando se abre desde safari (Iphone), el fondo o la barra dondese muestra la hora, la batería, la señal, etc etc, se cambia a un color que no está definido. Pero cuando lo ves bien modifica esa barra del celular, y la vdd que está horrible, claramente el cliente lo quiere sacar, pero no encuentro la solución ni siquiera con un webkit.
Al sitio lo trasladaron a WP, y no encuentro la forma de cambiarlo, y no encuentro ni siquiera el título del problema, y es un problema xq tampoco encuentro la solución al no saber de qué se trata esto. ¿Habrá alguien que sepa y pueda ayudarme?

Les dejo la muestra. Calculo que se puede modificar desde el css, a menos que sea un tema del mismo safari.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La web es: [www.maranathaargentina.com](http://www.maranathaargentina.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El color de la barra del navegador se puede cambiar usando una etiqueta meta:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF">
```

Pero es un valor sugerido, el navegador puede no respetar esto y cambiar el color por otro, con el objetivo de presentar un mejor contraste. Suele pasar cuando el color no calza en los modos light/dark

Esto último es lo que creo que pasa en tu caso, ya que tienes el color en `#FFFFFF` (blanco) y a ti te lo muestra en azul.